# Why is jest-haste-map reporting errors in my parent directory?

Tags: react-native, jestjs

When I do `npx react-native run-android` I'm suddenly getting a bunch of jest-haste-map module naming collision errors like this:

```
jest-haste-map: Haste module naming collision: Foo
  The following files share their name; please adjust your hasteImpl:
    * <rootDir>/Development/username/Foo/package.json
    * <rootDir>/Development/username2/Foo/package.json
```

I'm running `npx react-native start` from the directory `<rootDir>/Development/Bar` and am running `npx react-native start` from the directory `<rootDir>/Development/Bar/App`, so why is jest-haste-map concerning itself with errors in the parent directory `Development`?

In the error example above, I do intentionally have two copies of `Foo/` at slightly different paths because I was making a quick backup while trying an experiment. It ought to be valid for both to exist. And there's no reason why the react native code I'm running in `/Bar` should care.

What could be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I've confirmed it's something that's affecting watchman settings. I can run `watchman watch-del-all` and then `watchman watch-list` to confirm I've cleared it out, but when I do `npx react-native start` it sets watchman to watching /Users/username instead of /Users/username/Development/Bar

Haven't figured out why though, but maybe that's a different question since jest-haste-map is, I guess, reporting accurately since it's scanning through every directory on my computer

Edit: So the issue was that I had a separate installation of watchman on my machine?  My yarn.lock shows the existence of fb-watchman.  I did `brew uninstall watchman` to remove regular watchman and now everything works and builds without issue.